# System running extremely slowly after chkdsk /f and bsod

Tags: windows, ssd, performance, bsod, chkdsk

[Windows 10 Home]

After getting a bsod with the Kernel Security Check Failure error I performed various suggested checks on my system, being a malware scan, Window's memory diagnostics tool, sfc/scannow, driver verifier and chkdsk /f.

A few system files were repaired, but other than that none of the tests reported any issues. Rebooting worked as usual up to this point. After checkdisk however, booting suddenly started taking 3 minutes+ instead of the usual 10 seconds. Other than that, most interactions with the system are very slow. Accessing the file explorer, starting up software etc. All SMART values are all fine, I performed benchmarks on the SSD and CPU, nothing unusual here. The task manager / resource monitor also don't show an unusual load on any of the resources. Rerunning some of the checks didn't return any different results.

I have no more ideas what the cause of the problem could be in this context. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I decided to reset Windows. Boot times are still very slow and the system crashes every time on the login screen. Safe mode still works but I wouldn't know how to continue from there.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure, the slow boot times, is an indication the drive is not healthy.  I would replace it today, and stop using the current drive, in order to provide you a chance to pull the data off it.  The more you use it the worst the drive will get.

Comment: More causes of this error>>>>>>>https://windowsreport.com/kernel-security-check-failure-windows/

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose the issue, make a [Live USB flash drive with another OS, e.g. Linux.](https://linuxhint.com/rufus_bootable_usb_install_ubuntu_18-04_lts/) This usually can be done in a half-hour or so. Boot from the USB drive, but do *not* mount the HDD, and see if all is OK.

- If the PC runs well under the alternate OS, then the likely issues are either

  - Hardware failure, e.g. the HDD (despite SMART results), or
  - Windows OS issues, not caught by [DISM](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image) (which I assume you've tried, as well as SFC).
  - Try accessing the HDD, read-only, to see if it responds quickly.
- To attempt another fix of Windows, download the ISO and install to USB with Microsoft's [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). *However*, as @Ramhound warns, **save all data from the HDD before making any changes!** Imaging the whole disk is safest. Use the Windows Installation Media to reinstall Windows, keeping data.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I don't have any USB drives at hand currently, I'll have to try that tomorrow.
I can boot into safe mode successfully and access the drives without any issues. It took me a while to find a working ISO for DISM's restore health, however, that didn't help. Windows currently crashes during the login screen outside safe mode. Would you assume that the drive is fine?

Comment: If it runs and keeps running for hours or days in Safe mode, it's not likely a HDD issue. I'd make a disk image, then reinstall Windows, trying to keep files.